# JPA ManyToMany Not Populating Object Property

Tags: java, jpa

In JPA, I am trying to create an Update screen for an JPA object with a list of categories for that object. This is a many to many relationship.

I am creating a join relationship on the table within the JPA object that has the following properties.

Classes.java

```
@JoinTable(name = "classes_has_class_categories",joinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "classes_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "class_categories_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<ClassCategories> classCategoriesCollection;
```

The key to my question is contained within the below logic as I have updated the database and everything is great within the DB. However, my problem is that when I access the object at a later time, the classCategoriesCollection property within the object doesn't have all of the correct objects. I would have thought that my flush and refresh calls below would have synchronized everything up with the database, but that object property is still empty UNTIL I redeploy/recompile the application. Please help me with knowing how to get this object to sync up with the current database in the object.

ClassManager.java

```
for(String c : cats)
{
      int cId = ConvertToInt(c);
      ClassCategories ca = em.find(ClassCategories.class, cId);

      if(ca != null)
      {

        try{
           if(!cla.getClassCategoriesCollection().contains(ca))
           {
               ClassHasCategoriesPK classHasCategoriesPK= new ClassHasCategoriesPK();

               classHasCategoriesPK.setCategoryId(ca.getId());
               classHasCategoriesPK.setClassId(cla.getId());

                ClassHasCategories cd = new ClassHasCategories(classHasCategoriesPK);

                em.persist(cd);
                em.flush();                               

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {}    
        }
      }

      em.persist(cla); //cla is the Class object instance.
      em.flush();
      em.refresh(cla);
```

Later on in the code....

```
request.setAttribute("classCategories",cl.getClassCategoriesCollection());
```

Doesn't have the right classes until a recompile of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have a `ClassHasCategories` class for a M_N relationship table when your relationship has no extra parameters? Since `Classes` has a `@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` relationship with `ClassCategories`, all you need to be doing is something like:

```
classObj.getClassCategoriesCollection().add(classCategoryObj);
em.merge(classObj).
```

The provider will take care of updating the relationship table. You can also remove items from `classCategoriesCollection` using similar logic:

```
classObj.getClassCategoriesCollection().remove(classCategoryObj);
em.merge(classObj).
```

So, the answer is:

- If `classes_has_class_categories` has no columns but the pk with two fks, get ride of `ClassHasCategories` and `ClassHasCategoriesPK`. Work with `classCategoriesCollection` to update the relationship table.
- If `classes_has_class_categories` has extra columns, then redo your mapping in a way that `ClassHasCategoriesPK` has two `@ManyToOne` relationships, respectively for `Classes` and `ClassCategories`. Update relationships by directly manipulating `ClassHasCategories`. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/) is a code example.

The rule of thumb is, never mix both strategies (like you are doing by having both a `@ManyToMany` relationship and a separate `ClassHasCategories` object for the same table).

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks, new to JPA and am still figuring out how to map the relationships appropriately. I need to pickup a solid book.

Comment: Glad to be of service. JPA has its idiosyncrasies, some of which will drive even experienced programs nuts until they find out in practice about how things are supposed to be done. What I can say is: "Been there, done that".